# Applying File Stat (struct type of stat) across all Operating Systems

Tags: c++, c, windows, linux

I want to know how to apply `file stat(struct stat)` across all OS.

For example, I have a file stat of a file in Windows OS in the form of `struct stat`. I copied that file to a Linux OS. But now, I need to apply the `file stat` to Linux OS. Is there any method to use this for all OS? Do I need to convert the windows stat to some other format before applying it to Linux OS?

File Stat in the sense that I mean that Last Modified Time, File Created Time and Accessed Time etc.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean that you want the files on both systems to have the same creation timestamp, modified timestamp, etc?

Some *metadata*, like the timestamps, can be set for almost all operating systems. Other field can not be transferred, or need special processing. These include things like the rights of the file (read-write-execute) and user/group.

To change the timestamps on the Linux system, see the command [`touch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/touch) if you want to do it through the command line, and the function [`utime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/utime) if you want to do it in your own program.

**Edit:** After you clearing things up with your comment, you should know that the `stat` structure on Windows and Linux are not the same! There are more fields in the Linux `stat` structure, and the order is probably not the same as well. If you want to transfer this data between systems, your best bet is to create your own structure, containing the exact data you need, and have functions on each operating system that translates from/to the native `stat` structure.

Comment: Thanks for your info. Yes i want to have the timestamp details (created, modified and accessed time) same as that of the source file in Windows by programming. I wonder how the zip and other programs are keeping these time stamp details intact on various OS.

Comment: To tell in short about my program, i am just adding the stat details at the end of file (in Windows OS) and send it to another machine (Linux OS in my case). Upon receiving the file in Linux OS, i need to retrieve those stat details and apply that to the file now in Linux OS. I hope that i need to do some processing before applying the stat constructed from windows OS to the file in Linux OS. Can you tell me the conversions need to be done for this ?

Comment: @Prabu Updated my answer after your comments.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will try checking this by creating my own structure and also the functions to convert the structure(Windows or Linux) to my format and then again converting to the format required by the target OS. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. `stat` is a POSIX call that accepts `struct stat *` and fills it in. You can't copy that filled in structure to another POSIX system and expect the format to be the same, but you can certainly invoke `stat` on a copy of the file under another POSIX system.

Comment: I wonder how does the zip utility keeps the file stat details intact irrespective of the OS. For example if i take a zip of a file in Linux machine and then copy that to a Windows machine. Upon unzipping the same in Windows OS, i can get the same timestamp details. Not sure how they implemented internally. I want to have a similar thing.